# Batch Rename Image Files

Tags: terminal, console, mv

I have a folder with several pictures. I would like to convert the file names all into small letters and then delete all occurrences of certain strings.

For example, from `BILD02_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg` then the `cmyk`, `render`, `3d` and `_` should be deleted when connected to the words. So far, I have the following combo, but it will be the first passage only the first occurrence removed and not every.

```
// Rename names to lowercase
for file in *; 
do 
   mv "$file" "$file.tmp"; 
   mv "$file.tmp" "`echo $file | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`"; 
done

// Remove cmyk from filename
// optimierung: macht es nur einmal bei einer datei - ----
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/cmyk/}"; done
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/freigestellt/}"; done
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/-/_}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rename -n '$_=lc; s/(cmyk|freigestellt|render|3d|_|-)//g' *.jpg
```

This uses the **perl** rename command (also known as `prename` and `file-rename`).  It is **not** to be confused with the `rename` command from util-linux, which has completely different command-line options and capabilities.

It first converts the filename to lowercase using perl's `lc()` function, then removes all the words and characters you mentioned in either your text or your example code.

The `-n` option causes the `rename` to be a dry-run - it will only show you what it would do if you let it.  To make it actually rename the files, remove the `-n` or replace it with `-v` for verbose output.

e.g.

```
$ touch BILD{00..05}_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg
$ rename -v '$_=lc; s/(cmyk|freigestellt|render|3d|_|-)//g' *.jpg
BILD00_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild00.jpg
BILD01_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild01.jpg
BILD02_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild02.jpg
BILD03_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild03.jpg
BILD04_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild04.jpg
BILD05_CMYK_freigestellt_RENDER_3D.jpg renamed as bild05.jpg
```

Comment: BTW, if you're running debian or similar `sudo apt-get install file-rename`.  Other distros probably have it packaged too.  You can also find it on `CPAN` at https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename

Comment: Thank you very much.

`rename -v '$_=lc; s/(front|cmyk|freigestellt|render|3d|_|-)//g' *.(jpg|png)`